# Convert char* to int

Tags: c

Is there any way to convert `char *` to `int`?

I have a string (`string1`) of characters received from UART. This string looks like: `{3600,32,300}`:

```
char t1_s[32],t2_s[32],t3_s[32];

static char string1[15];

strcpy(t3_s, strtok(string1 , ","));
strcpy(t2_s, strtok(NULL,     ","));
strcpy(t1_s, strtok(NULL,     ","));

t1= t1_s - '0';
t2= t2_s - '0';
t3= t3_s - '0';
```

and the compiler gives a warning:

> #515-D a value of type "char *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "int"    main.c

I need to get the values of `t1_s`, `t2_s`, and `t3_s` as integers.

Comment: What is `t1_s - '0'` supposed to mean?

Comment: `char *` is a pointer. Conversion is implementation defined, buit you should always use `uintptr_t` or `intptr_t`, never `int` or another standard integer type.

Answer (score 0):

Use `strtol` to convert strings to integers:

```
char *s = "3600";
char *error = NULL;
int n = strtol(s, &error, 10);
if (*error != '\0') {
     // handle error
}
```

Comment: @Joshua yeah, scanf would be simpler, no tokenize needed. :)

Answer (score 0):

If your input is formatted consistently, you can also use `sscanf()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int 
main(int argc, const char** argv) 
{
    char inputString[] = "{3600,32,300}";
    int t1, t2, t3;

    sscanf(inputString, "{%d,%d,%d}", &t1, &t2, &t3);
    fprintf(stdout, "t1 [%d] t2 [%d] t3 [%d]\n", t1, t2, t3);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

To compile and run:

```
$ gcc -Wall so36774337.c -o so36774337
$ ./so36774337
t1 [3600] t2 [32] t3 [300]
```

Comment: not working,  using it on MSP430, embedded pprogramming. 
I´m receiving via UART this string {3600,32,300} and after that  it should run code which will work with this values .... But it still not working.

Comment: I don't know anything about your target. It might help if you post your compile warnings and error messages, runtime warnings or error messages, etc. Or use a tokenization approach described in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it something like this:

```
char *string1 = "3600,32,300";
char *next;

t1=strtol(string1, &next, 10);
++next; // skip the ','
t2=strtol(string1, &next, 10);
++next; // skip the ','
t3=strtol(string1, &next, 10);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are sure that your char array is a number you can use:

```
int i = atoi (charArray);
```